# Почему js-код в сафари работает иначе?

Tags: javascript

извините возможно глупый вопрос, но такая проблема, в хроме анимация работает правильно, а в сафари, когда скролю вверх до самого конца, меня исчезает. В хроме все нормально

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
 var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
 if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
   document.querySelector('.menu-bottom').style.transform = "translateY(0)";
 } else{
   document.querySelector('.menu-bottom').style.transform = "translateY(-200px)";
 }
 prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: ошибки в консоли?

Comment: если оно исчезает, значит меню реагирует на `js` и код отрабатывает. это ведь логично? сконцентрируйтесь на стилях

Comment: @Grundy изменил else if(prevScrollpos < currentScrollPos && currentScrollPos > 0) все хорошо в сафари стало